# Pulling information from a sqlite list

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I have a SQLite Database that I place multiple points of information into (name, DOB, location, etc.) using user input TKinter widgets.

I created a form for the users and it works fine. I then created a "reverse form" for administrators.  It extracts the data from the database and plugs it back into a read only format so admins can see exactly how it was submitted.

I then created a search function that displays basic results from the database.  I then used a button for admins to click to bring up the more detailed information via reverse form.

My problem is that when I pull the reverse form it only pulls the last entry in the search results to fill in the form.  I need for each database entry to pull up the corresponding information that goes with it.

```
def retrieve_result(self):    

    con = sql_connect(self)
    self.data_retrieval = con.cursor()
    self.data_retrieval.execute('SELECT * FROM Raw_data WHERE first_name=(?)', (self.first_name_field.get(),))
    return self.data_retrieval.fetchall()

    sql_close(con)


def display_results(self):
    results = self.retrieve_result()

    for index, data_list in enumerate(results,10):
        Button(self.frame, text=(data_list[0] +" " + data_list[1]),
command=self.retrieve_form).grid(row=index+1, column=0)
        Label(self.frame, text=data_list[2]).grid(row=index+1, column=1)

        self.db_first_name = StringVar(value=data_list[0])
        self.db_last_name = StringVar(value=data_list[1])
        self.db_dob = StringVar(value=data_list[2])

def retrieve_form(self):

    self.first_name_field = Entry(self.frame, state=DISABLED, disabledbackground="gray95", disabledforeground="black",textvariable=self.db_first_name, bg="white") 
    self.first_name_field.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=N) 

    self.last_name_field = Entry(self.frame, state=DISABLED, disabledbackground="gray95", disabledforeground="black", textvariable=self.db_last_name, bg="white")
    self.last_name_field.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=N)

    self.age_field = Entry(self.frame, state=DISABLED, disabledbackground="gray95", disabledforeground="black", textvariable=self.db_dob, bg="white") 
    self.age_field.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=N, padx=10)
```

The code is much more complex but I think I captured what is needed for assistance.  Like I said I can pull all the database information into the Kernel, but the form only retrieves the last entry in the database instead of each entry creating its own unique information.

Answer (score 0):

In `for`-loop you assings all values to the same variables

```
    self.db_first_name = StringVar(value=data_list[0])
    self.db_last_name = StringVar(value=data_list[1])
    self.db_dob = StringVar(value=data_list[2])
```

so then you can have only last value.

Better assingn to every `Button` function with these values so every `Button` will run function `retrieve_form` with different values. It needs `lambda` function to create this function because `command` expect function without arguments.

```
def display_results(self):

    results = self.retrieve_result()

    for index, data_list in enumerate(results,10):

        a = data_list[0]
        b = data_list[1]
        c = data_list[2]

        Button(self.frame, 
            text=...,
            command=lambda x=a, y=b, z=c:self.retrieve_form(x, y, z)
        ).grid(...)

        Label(self.frame, text=...).grid(...)
```

and function has to get values and use with `text=`

```
def retrieve_form(self, a, b, c):

    self.first_name_field = Entry(self.frame, text=a, ...) 

    self.last_name_field = Entry(self.frame, text=b, ...)

    self.age_field = Entry(self.frame, text=b, ...) 

    # rest
```

`lambda` has to use `x=a, y=b, z=c` because `lambda:self.retrieve_form(a, b, c)` will use the same last values with all buttons.

---

Instead of values you can use `index` but you have to keep values in `self.results` instead of `results

```
def display_results(self):

    self.results = self.retrieve_result() # <-- self

    for index, data_list in enumerate(results,10):

        Button(self.frame, 
            text=...,
            command=lambda x=index:self.retrieve_form(x)
        ).grid(...)

        Label(self.frame, text=...).grid(...)


def retrieve_form(self, index):

    data_list =  self.results[index]

    a = data_list[0]
    b = data_list[1]
    c = data_list[2]

    self.first_name_field = Entry(self.frame, text=a, ...) 

    self.last_name_field = Entry(self.frame, text=b, ...)

    self.age_field = Entry(self.frame, text=b, ...) 

    # rest
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help me. It gives me an index error. It is treating data_list as the original nested list (2 sample values of 130 subvalues). So data_list[0] is [First Name Last Name DOB etc] instead of [First Name].

Comment: do you use second version ? did you use `data_list =  self.results[index]` ?